# Name for numbers of the form (x)(x±1)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, square-numbers

I would like to know if there is a formal name for numbers of the form (x)(x±1). Ie, the numbers that fall between the perfect squares: 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, etc.

Comment: They are twice [triangular numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Comment: No special name to the best of my knowledge. They can be described as products of consecutive integers. They are also twice the corresponding triangular number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of numbers you asked about is  the
[OEIS sequence A002378](https://oeis.org/A002378) named

> Oblong (or promic, pronic, or heteromecic) numbers: a(n) = n*(n+1).

The OEIS entry also comments

> The word "pronic" (used by Dickson) is incorrect.

However, the mistake seems due to Euler and so just
as his mistake in naming Pell's equation it has stuck.

There is much more information about the sequence in the OEIS entry.

Comment: However, from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PronicNumber.html (about the pronic/promic confusion): "However, "pronic" seems to be a misspelling of "promic" (from the Greek promekes, meaning rectangular, oblate, or oblong). However, no less an authority than Euler himself used the term "pronic," so attempting to "correct" it at this late date seems inadvisable."

Comment: @Milten Thanks for that comment! I have added more context.

Answer (score 2):

No special name to the best of my knowledge. They can be described as products of consecutive integers. They are also twice the corresponding triangular number.